# Why won't this increment and store the value?

Tags: javascript

If I want to increment a value and then store it in another variable, why is it not possible to do it on one line of code?

This works

```
var count = 0;
count++;
var printer = count;
alert(printer); //Prints 1
```

But this doesn't

```
var count = 0;
var printer = count++;
alert(printer); //Prints 0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using the post-incrementing operator. The increment happens after the assignment expression is complete.

Use the pre-incrementing version instead...

```
++count;
```

Or use the `+=` operator...

```
count += 1;
```

- [MDN Operators documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Operators)

Answer (score 5):

You need to do

```
var count = 0;
var printer = ++count;
alert(printer);
```

The [JavaScript Arithmetic Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp) section of the w3schools page has a decent breakdown with a Try Me lab.  In short, if you do the increment/decrement operation before the variable, it will occur before it is used in the current operation.  If you include it afterwards, it will occur after the current operation.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in one line.

```
//Example 1
var count = 0;
count++;
var printer = count;
alert(printer); //Prints 1

//Example 2
var count2 = 0;
var printer2 = count2++;
alert(printer2);   //Prints 0
printer2 = count2++;
alert(printer2);   //Prints 1

// Example 3, in one line
var count2 = 0;
var printer2 = count2 + 1;
alert(printer2);   //Prints 1

// Example 4, in one line
var count2 = 0;
var printer2 = ++count2;
alert(printer2);   //Prints 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`++` changes the results depending on where you use it:

```
 y = 0;
 x = y++; // post-increment
```

is equivalent to

```
 y = 0;
 x = y;
 y = y + 1;
```

and

```
 x = ++y; // pre-increment
```

is equivalent to

```
 y = 0;
 y = y + 1;
 x = y;
```